# What is Cisco ACI command equivalent to Cisco IOS `show version`?

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

Based on this link, Cisco ACI is actually based on the Cisco Nexus 9000 family.

> The hardware for it is based on the Cisco Nexus 9000 family of
> switches.

https://www.sdxcentral.com/data-center/definitions/what-is-cisco-aci/

But when Cisco Nexus or IOS do have `show version` command, why don't Cisco ACI have similar command?

I would like to know more about this device, like model number, software version etc.

What is the right command for Cisco ACI? Probably something equivalent to Cisco IOS `show version`?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Each ACI switch can show you version output via `show version`

```
LEAF-101# show version
Cisco Nexus Operating System (NX-OS) Software
TAC support: http://www.cisco.com/tac
Documents: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9372/tsd_products_support_series_home.html
Copyright (c) 2002-2014, Cisco Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.
The copyrights to certain works contained in this software are
owned by other third parties and used and distributed under
license. Certain components of this software are licensed under
the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2.0 or the GNU
Lesser General Public License (LGPL) Version 2.1. A copy of each
such license is available at
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php and
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.php

Software
  BIOS:      version 05.39
  kickstart: version 14.2(4i) [build 14.2(4i)]
  system:    version 14.2(4i) [build 14.2(4i)]
  PE:        version 4.2(4i)
  BIOS compile time:       08/30/2019
  kickstart image file is: /bootflash/aci-n9000-dk9.14.2.4i.bin
  kickstart compile time:  04/21/2020 09:45:55 [04/21/2020 09:45:55]
  system image file is:    /bootflash/auto-s
  system compile time:     04/21/2020 09:45:55 [04/21/2020 09:45:55]


Hardware
  cisco N9K-C9348GC-FXP ("supervisor")
   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1526 @ 1.80GHz with 24437760 kB of memory.
  Processor Board ID XXXXXXXXXXX

  Device name: LEAF-101
  bootflash:    125029376 kB

Kernel uptime is 278 day(s), 16 hour(s), 17 minute(s), 37 second(s)

Last reset at 153000 usecs after Fri May 15 21:48:02 2020 EET
  Reason: system-power-cycled-due-to-ssd-firmware-upgrade
  System version: 14.2(4i)
  Service: module reloaded

plugin
  Core Plugin, Ethernet Plugin
```

`show version` command executed on the APIC will display software versions of the fabric elements:

```
APIC-1# show version
 Role        Pod         Node        Name          Version
 ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  --------------------
 controller  1           1           APIC-1          4.2(4i)
 controller  1           2           APIC-2          4.2(4i)
 controller  1           3           APIC-3          4.2(4i)
 leaf        1           101         LEAF-101        n9000-14.2(4i)
 leaf        1           102         LEAF-102        n9000-14.2(4i)
 leaf        1           103         LEAF-103        n9000-14.2(4i)
 leaf        1           104         LEAF-104        n9000-14.2(4i)
 leaf        1           105         LEAF-105        n9000-14.2(4i)
 leaf        1           106         LEAF-106        n9000-14.2(4i)
 spine       1           201         SPINE-201       n9000-14.2(4i)
 spine       1           202         SPINE-202       n9000-14.2(4i)
```

To run command remotely on leaf/spine from APIC, type `fabric NODE_ID <command>`:

```
APIC-1# fabric 101 show version

APIC-1# fabric 104-106,202 show version
```

Comment: Hmm, wasn't sure why my ACI switch can't run `show version`

Comment: @user11392987, what output do you get?